# How to get Total Page Load time from Har File

Tags: firebug, har

I am using HarLib to read Har Files from within my Java project. The example provided on the site helps to get the time taken to load each request. How do I get the total Load time for a Web Page. The OnLoad time will not help me as I have XHR requests happening even after the content load. How do I get the time shown in screenshot when I look at Firebug from within the HarLib (The one marked in red in the image):

[image]

Comment: You tried [this](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/) ?

Comment: Yes but it gives me time for each call. I want a way to get the total time. I can't add the time taken for each call as I have a number of parallel calls and it will give me a wrong number. The way I see it in Firebug is that, at the end it gives the total requests and the time taken for all the requests to complete. I know this will be recorded in har file. How do I read this particular value using harlib

Comment: This question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745931/how-to-get-total-web-page-response-time-from-a-har-file).